# Getting attribute list of a particular WMS layer and display it as a popup in OpenLayers3?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have an OpenLayers3 map with two layers provided from local GeoServer.My requirement is to get the attribute list of one layer and display it as a pop up inside the map window. To achieve this, I wrote something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        .ol-zoom {
          top: 52px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options {
          z-index: 1000;
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 2px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 8px;
          top: 8px;
        }
        #updateFilterButton, #resetFilterButton {
          height: 22px;
          width: 22px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none !important;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin: 1px;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold !important;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white !important;
          padding: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a {
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white;
          display: block;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-size: 19px;
          font-weight: bold;
          height: 22px;
          line-height: 11px;
          margin: 1px;
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          width: 22px;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a:hover {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.7);
        }
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            border: none;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */
        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom:802px;
            left:450px;
        }
        #left_frame
        {

            position: relative;
            width: 590px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom:1635px;
            left:1060px;
        }
        img{
            position: relative;
            width: 444px;
            height: 775px;

            top:5px;

        }
        #legend {
            position: relative;
            width: 444px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            top:0px;

        }
        #wrapper {
            width: 444px;
            position: relative;
            bottom:802px;
            left:450px;
        }
        #location {


            bottom:802px;
            left:450px;
        }

        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
        table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }
        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }
        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="legend">
      <img src="Legend.PNG.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="map"><div id="info"></div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location"></div>
        <div id="scale"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left_frame">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Village Boundary" checked>Village Boundary<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="OSM Grids">OSM Grids<br></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


      var pureCoverage = false;
      // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
      // and default to jpeg format
      var format = 'image/png';
      var bounds = [472440.0520989996, 911801.0984444692,
                    768802.9061656371, 1424302.9894040015];
      if (pureCoverage) {
        document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
        format = "image/jpeg";
      }

      var supportsFiltering = true;
      if (!supportsFiltering) {
        document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
      }

      var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('location'),
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });

      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:32643',
          units: 'm',
          axisOrientation: 'neu',
          global: false
      });




        var villageboundary = new ol.layer.Image({
                 title:'Village Boundary',
                 type: 'base',
                 label:'Village Boundary',
                 source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                 ratio: 1,
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                 params: {'FORMAT': format,
                         'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                         "LAYERS": 'geog585:Village_Boundary',
                         "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                         }
                       })
                     });





         var osmgrid = new ol.layer.Image({
                 title:'OSM Grid',
                 visible: false,
                 label:'OSM Grid',
                 source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                 ratio: 1,

                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                 params: {'FORMAT': format,
                         'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                         "LAYERS": 'geog585:OSM_Grid_25000_include_hazard_line',
                         "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                         }
                       })
                     });





         //Tile OSM

         var tiledOSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title:'OSM Grids',
        visible: false,
        label:'OSM Grids',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format, 
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                   tiled: true,
                "LAYERS": 'geog585:OSM_Grid_25000_include_hazard_line',
                "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
             tilesOrigin: 472849.4548000004 + "," + 912420.9497999996
          }
        })
      });




         //Tile OSM



      var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
                villageboundary,

                tiledOSM
               ],
        view: new ol.View({
           projection: projection
        })
      });



      map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt) {
        var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');
        var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
        var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
        var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
        var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
        if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
          scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
        } else if (scale >= 950000) {
          scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
        } else {
          scale = Math.round(scale);
        }
        document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML = "Scale = 1 : " + scale;
      });
      map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());


      var changeLayer = function changeLayer(ev) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
      if (layer.get('label') === val) {
        layer.setVisible(checked);
        } 
      });
     };

    $('input').each(function (){  $(this).on('change', changeLayer); });



    /////popup//

      var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
     map.addOverlay(popup);

     map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    popup.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = tiledOSM.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:32643',
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
    if (url) {
    popup.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
        '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }

    popup.show(evt.coordinate, url);
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is not working. Since I am new to this, I do not know if I have to add any extra scripts/elements. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open an iframe, instead of it, you can have the data as JSON, parse, show.

Try this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .ol-zoom {
            top: 52px;
        }

        .ol-toggle-options {
            z-index: 1000;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 8px;
            top: 8px;
        }

        #updateFilterButton,
        #resetFilterButton {
            height: 22px;
            width: 22px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            line-height: 22px;
            margin: 1px;
            font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            background: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
            color: white !important;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .ol-toggle-options a {
            background: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
            color: white;
            display: block;
            font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 22px;
            line-height: 11px;
            margin: 1px;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 22px;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .ol-toggle-options a:hover {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.7);
        }

        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            border: none;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */

        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }

        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom: 802px;
            left: 450px;
        }

        #left_frame {
            position: relative;
            width: 590px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom: 1635px;
            left: 1060px;
        }

        img {
            position: relative;
            width: 444px;
            height: 775px;
            top: 5px;
        }

        #legend {
            position: relative;
            width: 444px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            top: 0px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 444px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 802px;
            left: 450px;
        }

        #location {
            bottom: 802px;
            left: 450px;
        }
        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */

        table.featureInfo,
        table.featureInfo td,
        table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }

        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }

        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="legend">
        <img src="Legend.PNG.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
        <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
        <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location"></div>
        <div id="scale"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left_frame">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Village Boundary" checked>Village Boundary
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="OSM Grids">OSM Grids
        <br>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pureCoverage = false;
        // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
        // and default to jpeg format
        var format = 'image/png';
        var bounds = [472440.0520989996, 911801.0984444692,
            768802.9061656371, 1424302.9894040015
        ];
        if (pureCoverage) {
            document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
            format = "image/jpeg";
        }

        var supportsFiltering = true;
        if (!supportsFiltering) {
            document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
        }

        var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
            className: 'custom-mouse-position',
            target: document.getElementById('location'),
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
            undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
        });

        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:32643',
            units: 'm',
            axisOrientation: 'neu',
            global: false
        });

        var villageboundary = new ol.layer.Image({
            title: 'Village Boundary',
            type: 'base',
            label: 'Village Boundary',
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                ratio: 1,
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                params: {
                    'FORMAT': format,
                    'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                    "LAYERS": 'geog585:Village_Boundary',
                    "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                }
            })
        });

        var osmgrid = new ol.layer.Image({
            title: 'OSM Grid',
            visible: false,
            label: 'OSM Grid',
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                ratio: 1,

                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                params: {
                    'FORMAT': format,
                    'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                    "LAYERS": 'geog585:OSM_Grid_25000_include_hazard_line',
                    "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                }
            })
        });

        //Tile OSM

        var tiledOSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'OSM Grids',
            visible: false,
            label: 'OSM Grids',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                params: {
                    'FORMAT': format,
                    'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                    tiled: true,
                    "LAYERS": 'geog585:OSM_Grid_25000_include_hazard_line',
                    "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                    tilesOrigin: 472849.4548000004 + "," + 912420.9497999996
                }
            })
        });

        //Tile OSM

        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attribution: false
            }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                villageboundary,

                tiledOSM
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: projection
            })
        });

        map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt) {
            var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');
            var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
            var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
            var mpu = ol.proj.Units.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
            var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
            if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
                scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
            } else if (scale >= 950000) {
                scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
            } else {
                scale = Math.round(scale);
            }
            document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML = "Scale = 1 : " + scale;
        });
        map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());

        var changeLayer = function changeLayer(ev) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
                if (layer.get('label') === val) {
                    layer.setVisible(checked);
                }
            });
        };

        $('input').each(function() {
            $(this).on('change', changeLayer);
        });

        /////popup//
        var container = document.getElementById('popup');
        var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
        var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
        var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
            element: container,
            autoPan: true,
            autoPanAnimation: {
                duration: 250
            }
        });
        closer.onclick = function() {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
            closer.blur();
            return false;
        };
        map.addOverlay(overlay);

        map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
            var view = map.getView();
            var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (map.getView().getResolution());
            var url = villageboundary.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate, view.getResolution(), view.getProjection(), {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                'PIXELRADIUS': 5,
                'FEATURE_COUNT': 10
            });
            if (url) {
                content.innerHTML =
                    'URL: ' + url;
            }

            overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried with your code. It worked when I tried to display the url in a pop up. But when I tried to parse the JSON data and display property name and value, it shows nothing. Can you correct me if it is wrong.  JSFiddle link  is given. https://jsfiddle.net/jomiracle/cehjva0m/2/

Comment: The pop up was blank because of CORS error and I fixed it by adding Moesif CORS extension to Chrome browser.Now,the pop up appeared with expected result.